# Spring Boot AJAX call API

Tags: ajax, spring

I tried write code for ajax call api from controller. I want ajax get content of link api. I have trouble write code ajax. Please help me write this code with ajax

RestController.java

```
@Responsebody
@GetMapping("api/hello")
public String hello (){
 return "Hello World";
```

Index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
   <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <button type="submit"  name ="clickPost"></button>

   </body>
   </html>
```

I want when I click button, website return strings Hello World. Please help me write code ajax execute this request, i'm newbie. If my code controller has error, please change it help me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your RestController.java is fine (only missing '}' ). There is actualy no ajax call from your index.html.
It can look somethink like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
       <script>
            function callAPI() {
                var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    console.log(this.responseText)
                  }
                };
                xhttp.open("GET", "/api/hello", true);
                xhttp.send();
            }
       </script>
   
   </head>
   <body>
    <button onClick="callAPI()">Click me</button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Depending on your particular environment you still might need to update the API URL in javascript or enabling CORS. Check these links
https://web.dev/cross-origin-resource-sharing/
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/